# Simplifcation of $p$-norm to the $ p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

If define the p-norm as $$||x||_p = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} |x_i|_p)^\frac{1}{p}$$
Can I state that $$||x||_p^p = ((\sum_{i=1}^{N} |x_i|_p)^\frac{1}{p})p = (\sum_{i=1}^{N} |x_i|_p)$$
This feels like a gross oversimplification, but I cannot seem to get it out of my head.

Comment: $a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2$?

Comment: Yes if $p=1$ ;)

Comment: What? If $a=b^{\frac1p}$, then $a^p=b$.